# Distinction between signers.key and signers.public_key in Account response

Tags: horizon

In the `signers` block of [an Account response](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBH25RYXAEDKPZUIMC5VJBKNYRUULY5B2LH5NVG6Q3RZPHK5KPFBZX7T):

```
"signers": [
  {
    "public_key": "GBH25RYXAEDKPZUIMC5VJBKNYRUULY5B2LH5NVG6Q3RZPHK5KPFBZX7T",
    "weight": 1,
    "key": "GBH25RYXAEDKPZUIMC5VJBKNYRUULY5B2LH5NVG6Q3RZPHK5KPFBZX7T",
    "type": "ed25519_public_key"
  }
]
```

Under what circumstances would `key` and `public_key` differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They wouldn't necessarily differ, but `public_key` is deprecated, most likely since we have other types of signers now, in addition to just ed25519 keys (which *are* public keys).

https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/d121c23554421abeb33273ef74114a30c41b409e/services/horizon/internal/docs/reference/resources/account.md